# Unable to know on how to work with session

Tags: java, session, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a weather app in Alexa using Java. Here my target is like this.

1. User enters a city name/country name.
2. My code decides if this is a city/country.
3. If it is a city, it will give the weather else it will prompt the user to give a city.
4. Based on the city, it will give the weather result.

My code is as below.

```
private String getTheCurrentWeather(Intent intent, Session session) {
    InputStreamReader inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String text = "";
    String result = "";
    String cityName = getCityName(intent);
    String checkIfItIsACountry = getCountryCode(cityName, session);
    String countryCode = (String) session.getAttribute("countryCode");
    try {
        String line;
        URL url = new URL(URL_PREFIX + cityName);
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        text = builder.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });

        Map<String, Double> mainMap = (Map<String, Double>) map.get("main");
        String cityN = map.get("name").toString();
        String cityNWithjoutSpace = map.get("name").toString().replace(" ", "");
        if (cityNWithjoutSpace.equalsIgnoreCase(cityName) && checkIfItIsACountry.length() == 0) {
            double x = mainMap.get("temp") - 273.15;
            result = "Weather in " + cityN + " is " + df2.format(x) + " degrees Celcius from block one";
        } else {
            if (checkIfItIsACountry.length() != 0) {
                result = "I can't get the weather of entire Country, please give me a city";

                result = getTheCurrentWeatherWithCountry(intent, session, countryCode);

            } else {
                result = "You have not entered a valid city";
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        text = "";
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
    }
    return result;
}

private String getTheCurrentWeatherWithCountry(Intent intent, Session session, String countryCode2) {
    InputStreamReader inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String text = "";
    String result = "";
    String cityName = getCityName(intent);
    String countryCode = (String) session.getAttribute("countryCode");
    try {
        String line;
        URL url = new URL(URL_PREFIX + cityName + "," + countryCode2);
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        text = builder.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });

        Map<String, Double> mainMap = (Map<String, Double>) map.get("main");
        String cityN = map.get("name").toString();
        String cityNWithjoutSpace = map.get("name").toString().replace(" ", "");
        double x = mainMap.get("temp") - 273.15;
        result = "Weather in " + cityN + " is " + df2.format(x) + " degrees Celcius  from block two";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        text = "";
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
    }
    return result;
}

private String getCityName(Intent intent) {
    Slot cityName = intent.getSlot(Slot_City);
    return cityName.getValue();
}// get Country Code using Locale
public String getCountryCode(String countryName, Session session) {
    String result = "";
    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
        if (countryName.equals(obj.getDisplayCountry().toString())) {
            result = obj.getCountry();
        }
    }
    session.setAttribute("countryCode", result);
    return result;
}
```

And my problem is like this.

When user gives city as input, it is giving the response correctly, But when The user giving input as country, instead of asking the user to input city, it is directly giving the weather of the capital city.

Please let me know how can I handle the sessions here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the API provides the capital city as a default if only the country is given. In this case you should check the string before creating the URL and only create the URL request if the string is NOT a country code.

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for this, I already checked it, You are true that the return type is capital city directly, But as per my code, it shoud append the city name and country code.

Comment: Do you have a link to the API? Perhaps there is a default value/null value you can include to prevent it from returning the capital city?